# Django template: why variable name evaluate to string

Tags: django

`turl1`, `turl2`...`ourl1`, `ourl2` are context variables (all strings) I am returning from view.

```
    {% for i in "1234" %}
    <div class="spot">
        {% with t="turl"|add:i %}
        {% with o="ourl"|add:i %}
            <a href= {{ o }}">
                <img src={{ t }}>
            </a>
        {% endwith %}
        {% endwith %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Right now I am getting this:

```
<a href="ourl1">
    <img src="turl1">
</a>
...
```

while `ourl1` and `turl1` should evaluate to url but it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove quotes in lines:

```
{% with t=turl1 %}
{% with o=ourl1 %}
```

If you want to iterate over it, you should pass in two arrays from your view.

```
{'urls': [[turl1, ourl1], [turl2, ourl2]]}
```

Then iterate over it in your template:

```
{% for t, o in urls %}
     <a href="{{ o }}">
         <img src="{{ t }}"/>
     </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I need a loop in template otherwise there will be many repetitive code. So cannot just hardcode turl1, turl2, turl3... The trailing number has to be added as loop index I think

Comment: As I've said in the answer, pass in an array.

Comment: When did you say about array thing? don't see it. anyway, could you post code example?

Answer (score 0):

If `turl1, turl2...ourl1, ourl2` are context variables then in the django templates you need to put them between `{ ... }`